# vue.js method can't access variable from data object with multiple rows

Tags: vuejs2

I am currently learning vue.js and having trouble accessing data in the methods.

data is loaded and set as a global variable (for now, this will probably change but not part of the problem now i think)

through ajax call this data is received:

data":[{"itemId":"58646f066803fa62388b4573","color":"#ffb878","name":"test1","startDate":"04/24/2017","work":"9.25"},{"itemId":"58646f066803fa62388b4572","color":"#ffb878","name":"test2","startDate":"04/24/2017","work":"4.25"},{"itemId":"58646f066803fa62388b4571","color":"#a4bdfc","name":"test3","startDate":"05/01/2017","work":"24.00"}]

which is set as a global (variable data is set outside of the functions) with:

...success:  function (jsonObj)
                {
data['item'] = jsonObj.data

....

now for the vue part:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el:'#canvas',
  data: {
    items: data['item']
  },
  methods: {
    moveItem: function(){
      console.log("new date: "+this.startDate);
    }
  }
})
```

the html:

```
<div v-for="row in items" class="entirerow" v-bind:id="'row'+row.itemId">
                                    <div class="itemrow">{{ row.name }}</div>
                                    <div class="itemrow"><input type="text" v-model="row.startDate" @change="moveItem"></div>
                                    <div class="itemrowlast">{{ row.work }}</div>

                            </div>
```

this nicely shows 3 rows with the correct data in each row. So far so good. But now if I change something in the input value the method moveItem is triggered but states "new date: undefined" in the console.log

I've tried console.log("new date: "+this.items.startDate) as well but no cigar and then it would seem the method wouldn't know which row is handled.

How can I access the correct data in the method, so from a certain row in the loop?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You refer to data object in method (**this.startDate**) not to item

```
moveItem: function(){
  console.log("new date: "+this.startDate);
}
```

You can change your code like this

**template**

```
@change="moveItem(row)"
```

**script**

```
moveItem: function(row){
  console.log("new date: " + row.startDate);
}
```